# How do i fix "TypeError: req.next is not a function" error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose

I am working on a project and i keep getting this error, and i have tried fixing it but i can't? I understand it but don't know how to fix it.

Here is the err:

```
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: req.next is not a function
    at done (C:\Users\Children\Desktop\Web Projects\App Line Planner\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1007:25)
    at tryRender (C:\Users\Children\Desktop\Web Projects\App Line Planner\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:642:5)
    at Function.render (C:\Users\Children\Desktop\Web Projects\App Line Planner\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\Children\Desktop\Web Projects\App Line Planner\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
    at C:\Users\Children\Desktop\Web Projects\App Line Planner\main.js:48:25
    at C:\Users\Children\Desktop\Web Projects\App Line Planner\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4866:16
    at C:\Users\Children\Desktop\Web Projects\App Line Planner\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4866:16
    at C:\Users\Children\Desktop\Web Projects\App Line Planner\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:24:16
    at C:\Users\Children\Desktop\Web Projects\App Line Planner\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4889:21
    at C:\Users\Children\Desktop\Web Projects\App Line Planner\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4400:11
    at C:\Users\Children\Desktop\Web Projects\App Line Planner\node_modules\kareem\index.js:136:16
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
Emitted 'error' event on Function instance at:
    at C:\Users\Children\Desktop\Web Projects\App Line Planner\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4868:13
    at C:\Users\Children\Desktop\Web Projects\App Line Planner\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:24:16
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
```

And from looking at the error i am pretty sure that the error is in this function:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    if (namee == "") {
        res.redirect('/login');
    } else {
        Item.find({ name: namee }, function (err, foundItemList) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } if (foundItemList) {
                console.log(namee);
                console.log("Found ITems: " + foundItemList);
                for (var i = 0; i < foundItemList.length; i++) {
                    res.render('main', { item: foundItemList, foundItems: foundItemList[i].initem });
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

And here is the full code:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/appline", { useUnifiedTopology: true }, { useNewUrlParser: true });

const itemSchema = {
    name: String,
    initem: Array,
    text: String,
    tab: Number
}

const Item = mongoose.model("Item", itemSchema);

const app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static('public'));

const items = [];
const tabs = [];

var namee = "";
var tabb = 0;

app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
    res.render('login');
});

app.post('/login', function (req, res) {
    namee = req.body.name;
    res.redirect('/');
})

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    if (namee == "") {
        res.redirect('/login');
    } else {
        Item.find({ name: namee }, function (err, foundItemList) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } if (foundItemList) {
                console.log(namee);
                console.log("Found ITems: " + foundItemList);
                for (var i = 0; i < foundItemList.length; i++) {
                    res.render('main', { item: foundItemList, foundItems: foundItemList[i].initem });
                }
            }
        });
    }
});

app.post('/addinitem', function (req, res) {

    tabb += 1;

    tex = req.body.addtoitem;

    const item2 = new Item({
        name: namee,
        initem: [],
        text: tex,
        tab: tabb
    });

    Item.find({ name: namee }, function (err, foundITems) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else if (foundITems) {
            foundITems.initem.push(item2);
            foundITems.save(function () {
                res.redirect('/');
            });
        }
    });

});

app.post('/add', function (req, res) {
    const item = req.body.newItem;
    console.log(item);
    items.push(item);
    const item1 = new Item({
        name: namee,
        initem: [],
        text: item
    });
    item1.save();
    console.log(item1);
    res.redirect('/');
});

app.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Server started on port 3000.');
});
```

Comment: Any chance you could refactor your code to only call `res.render` once? I am pretty sure calling it multiple times inside that `for` loop is what's causing the error.

Comment: Oh yea thanks! I will try that ans see if it works.

Comment: Also don't forget to put some kind of a render inside `if (err) {...`. Otherwise if `Item.find` throws an error, you won't render anything and the page will just hang.

Comment: Ok thanks it fixed the problem! Thanks a lot! Oh and after i am done with this project then i am going to publish it on our website or the Azi Tec Team website. And if you want to take a look at it and use it then here is the link to our website https://azitecteam.herokuapp.com/ and if you where to go to web apps then the app should be there by the end of the week.

Comment: This project is called App Lin Planner and the purpose is to help plan for apps or website or anything with programming. We also have other apps there as well if you want to check them out.

Comment: I will check it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your error could be that you're using `res.render` multiple times in the `for` loop, so you need to save those items that you want to show into an object, and pass it to the options in the `render` function.

Have a look at this code:

```js
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    var data = []
    if (namee == "") {
        return res.redirect('/login');
    } else {
        Item.find({ name: namee }, function (err, foundItemList) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } if (foundItemList) {
                console.log(namee);
                console.log("Found ITems: " + foundItemList);
                for (var i = 0; i < foundItemList.length; i++) {
                    let obj = {}
                    obj["item"] = foundItemList[i] // Look at this
                    obj["itemDesc"] = foundItemList[i].initem
                    data.append(obj)
                }
            }
        });
    }
    return res.render('main', { items: data }); // And then you can pass it like a array and you will enumerate it into the template engine
});
```